# Reversed For Loop - First iteration undefined

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why the first iteration of a reverse for-loop logs `undefined`?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for (var i = arr.length; i > -1; i--) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: var i = arr.length-1;

Comment: just for the sake of adding something: `arr.reverse().map( e => console.log(e) );` using lambda and the reverse prototype, which is supported since ecmascript's first edition. https://jsfiddle.net/uoe33kk6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first iteration, `i` is `arr.length`.

There's no element at index `arr.length`. The last element of a zero-based array is at index `arr.length-1`.

The usual way to iterate in reverse is

```
for (let i=arr.length; i-- > 0; ) {
```

(note that the condition decrements the counter and is executed before the content of the loop)

This can can also be simplified in JavaScript into

```
for (let i=arr.length; i--;) {
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c @DenysSeguret

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a while loop with a [postfix decrement `--`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement_(--)) instead of a justified `for` loop?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    i = arr.length;
  
while (i--) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: `while(i--)` What?

Comment: it just iterates to zero.

Comment: There's no real reason to downvote here. But note that this kind of loop doesn't make it easy to limit the scope of the counter to the loop (as is now possible with `let`).

Comment: Ah, shorthand, how silly of mine, carry on :). (I wasn't the guy that downvoted).

Comment: While this code is perfectly valid, it's got a very high wtf factor. It relies on the fact that 0 evaluates to false, confounding semantics with implementation peculiarities.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the length of the array from `arr.length` returns 8, and since the arrays in JavaScript are Zero-indexed (counting starts from 0), the last element in an array is at the index `arr.length - 1`

so to avoid the undefined, do this:

```
$(function(){

  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

  for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }

})
```